# Trying to find a particular object from JSON using angularJS and lodash using .find()

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework, lodash

This is the controller.

```
.controller('EventMapCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Events) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.EventId = Number($stateParams.id);
    Events.getEvents.then(function(data) {
        vm.event = _.find(data, {id: vm.EventId});
        console.log(vm.event);
    });

    $scope.vm = vm;
});
```

This is the `Events` service

```
.service('Events', function(mApi, mDomain) {
    return {
        getEvents: mApi.getData('/events/')
    }
});
```

So far I am able to make the http call and get all the events. However, what I am trying to particularly accomplish in the controller is from an oncoming data, I only want one event whose id is matched by `vm.EventId`. So far, I am getting an undefined error when I `console.log(vm.event)`. I'd appreciate any help. My understanding of angular is quite recent and I am not sure if I am using `.find()` right.

Answer (score 0):

No worries on using [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) here - we can instead use an [AngularJS Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). Observe the following simplified example. You can mold into your working copy from here...

```
// inject $filter
var items = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}];

var found = $filter('filter')(items, { id: 2 }, true); // { 'id': 2 }
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/L510w4gs/) - demo

Comment: Apparently, I am getting that my data json is not an array. Hence, filter cannot work with it. From my understanding, json is already an array of objects. Do i have to implement a code to change my data into an array before i use filter?

Comment: an endpoint of `events` not returning an array? Suspicious. Are you sure? You already mentioned "So far I am able to make the http call and get all the events" - where are they? What were you attempting with `_.find()` then?

Comment: It gives me back something like this. filter:notArray   got {"Data", [{_id:0350345ef43, eventName: hello}, {}]
this should mean that the http call is in effect but for some reason it's not an array. To be honest with you, I am following a pluralsight tutorial and the guy was using _.find(). However, implementing the same code did not work for me.

Comment: Ahh - try `$filter('filter')(data.Data`... It looks like your var of `data` has a property of `Data` which _is_ an array of objects

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort. So this was the initial error to be precise. Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {"data":[{"_id":"56283459e87d95119f124f5c","eventName":"Food takeaway!"

I implemented your suggestion and ended up with this
Events.getEvents.then(function(data){
      vm.Event = $filter('filter')(data.data, {id: vm.EventId}, true);
      console.log(vm.Event);
    })
The error is gone but it gives me back just an empty array. "[ ]"

Comment: You first said it was `.Data` and now it's `.data`? The latter is expected - the capital threw me off but that was the first error you specifically mentioned. Regardless, check out that property, its `_id` with an underscore. Change to the following `$filter('filter')(data.data, { _id: vm.EventId }, true);` [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/19sdevp8/)

Comment: @AnjilDhamala was this able to help you? Please share your results

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy with mid-term presentations and all. Not exactly. However i found my way around. I'll answer my question.

Comment: Why? My answer solves your answer _exactly_. I see you are making a habit of answering your own questions - SO is not a personal log of your own trial and error, just FYI

Comment: I do not know why you have such a terrible attitude about it. I did try both .Data and .data and also _id. It didn't make a difference. I can see that you want to make a name for yourself in the website. However, attacking another fellow user is not the right way to go about it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not trying to "attack" anybody, I am encouraging you to use the site correctly through blunt feedback. Other users are putting effort into helping you and you seem to not be very receptive according to your activity on here. I helped you debug this entire issue and you posted an answer that has nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it.
I added a different route on the server side which would allow me to make http call with an appended id. Futhermore, I also used a different service.
Here's the new service.

```
.service('Event', function(mApi,mDomain){
    var getEvent = function(id){
      return mApi.getData('/event/'+id);
    };
    return {
      getEvent: getEvent
    };
  })
```

And here is the controller. I have further implemented map's specific attributes. Hence, it will look significantly different than my original post.

```
.controller('EventMapCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Event) {
    var vm = this;
    Event.getEvent($stateParams.id).then(function (res) {
      vm.event = res.data;
      vm.map = {
        center: {
          latitude: vm.event.location.latitude,
          longitude: vm.event.location.longitude
        },
        zoom: 17
      };
      vm.marker = {
        id: 1,
        latitude: vm.event.location.latitude,
        longitude: vm.event.location.longitude,
        title: vm.event.location.name
      }
    });
    vm.locationClicked = function (marker) {
      window.location = "geo:" + marker.latitude + "," + marker.longitude + ";u=35";
    };
    $scope.vm = vm;
  })
```

Here is the specific line that I wanted to get done.

```
Event.getEvent($stateParams.id).then(function (res) {
          vm.event = res.data;
```

Comment: This is completely different than your original question, sorry - not helpful

Comment: Yes, it might seem so. But my original question was to get a specific event from a list of events. The route I was taking was not getting the results. I had to change the way I did it and then was able to accomplish. I am sorry that I wasted your time. I am sure your code would have worked perfectly if I had given a another go.